# How multi index database sync in all eos nodes?

Tags: storage

Contracts may change data in multi index databases, I wanna know how multi index database sync in all eos nodes?

- Option 1, all the eos nodes execute each contracts, so no need to
  sync.
- Option 2, only the current block producer execute contract, other nodes
  sync data directly. If so, does it use gossip protocol?
- Option 3, other mechanism, please share technical details.

Comment: option 1 is correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EOS uses a BFT consensus algorithm, so, by default, all nodes (producing and non-producing) validate and process all transactions and blocks to compute the state at each timestep.

However, [in the whitepaper](https://github.com/EOSIO/Documentation/blob/master/TechnicalWhitePaper.md#partial-evaluation-of-blockchain-state), there is a mention of an optional "Partial Evaluation of Blockchain State":

> **Partial Evaluation of Blockchain State**
>
> Scaling blockchain technology necessitates that components are
>   modular. Everyone should not have to run everything, especially if
>   they only need to use a small subset of the applications.
>
> An exchange application developer runs full nodes for the purpose of
>   displaying the exchange state to its users. This exchange application
>   has no need for the state associated with social media applications.
>   EOS.IO software allows any full node to pick any subset of
>   applications to run. Actions delivered to other applications are
>   safely ignored if your application never depends upon the state of
>   another contract.